# Why is this imbedding continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Define the imbedding $i_{x_{1}}: Y \rightarrow X \times Y$ by $i_{x_{1}}(y) = (x_1,y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces. Then supposedly $i_{x_{1}}$ is continuous, but I fail to see why; we need to show that $i_{x_{1}}^{-1}(O)$ is open, where $O$ is any open subset of $X \times Y$. I don't see why this is the case; can anyone provide me a proof of why the imbedding is continuous? Thanks in advance for your time and efforts.

Comment: you just need to check $i_{x_i}^{-1}(O)$ is open when $O$ is of the form $U\times V$ for $U$ open in $X$ and $V$ open in $Y$ (since such sets form a basis for the product topology). And $i_{x_1}^{-1}(U\times V) = \emptyset$ if $x_1 \not \in U$ and $V$ if $x_1 \in U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function $f : X \to Y \times Z$ is continuous iff $\pi_Y \circ f$ and $\pi_Z \circ f$ are both continuous. (univeral property of continuity of maps into products).

In our case:
$\pi_Y\circ i_{x_1} = \mathrm{id}_Y$ (the identity) and $\pi_X \circ i_{x_1} = c_{x_1}$ (a constant map) and both identities and constant maps are always continuous. Hence so is $i_{x_1}$.

Comment: Thank you; this wasn't an explicit theorem in my book, so I'm glad I asked.

Comment: @StevenWagter what book are you using then?

Comment: Bert Mendelson's introduction to topology; I just saw it was one of the exercises which I haven't done yet though.

Comment: @StevenWagter it’s a very handy fact to know about maps into products so do that exercise too. There are solutions on this site already and it’s shown in other standard texts like Munkres.

Answer (score 2):

One coordinate function is constant,  the other is the identity.   Both continuous. Since the product topology is the coarsest which makes the projections onto the coordinates continuous, we have the universal property @Henno refers to, and the map is continuous.